# Spring Data JDBC - Lazy Loading/Projection

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

For Spring Data JDBC, is lazy loading possible ? Or is projection possible ?

I would only want two fields in my data but it seems that Spring JDBC is fetching the whole thing.

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepo extends CrudRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    @Query("select id, firstname, lastname from m_appuser where firstname=:firstName")
    public AppUser findByAppUserName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
}
```

This resulted to getting all associated objects.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT "ROLE"."ID" AS "ID", "ROLE"."DEL" AS "DEL", "ROLE"."NAME" AS "NAME", "ROLE"."VERSION" AS "VERSION", "ROLE"."DISABLED" AS "DISABLED", "ROLE"."CREATED_DATE" AS "CREATED_DATE", "ROLE"."DESCRIPTION" AS "DESCRIPTION", "ROLE"."REFERENCE_NUMBER" AS "REFERENCE_NUMBER", "ROLE"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "createdBy"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_ID", "createdBy"."DEL" AS "CREATEDBY_DEL", "createdBy"."EMAIL" AS "CREATEDBY_EMAIL", "createdBy"."STATUS" AS "CREATEDBY_STATUS", "createdBy"."VERSION" AS "CREATEDBY_VERSION", "createdBy"."ENABLED" AS "CREATEDBY_ENABLED", "createdBy"."PASSWORD" AS "CREATEDBY_PASSWORD", "createdBy"."USER_TYPE" AS "CREATEDBY_USER_TYPE", "createdBy"."BRANCH_ID" AS "CREATEDBY_BRANCH_ID", "createdBy"."USERNAME" AS "CREATEDBY_USERNAME", "createdBy"."LASTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY_LASTNAME", "createdBy"."FIRSTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY_FIRSTNAME", "createdBy"."CLEAR_PSWD" AS "CREATEDBY_CLEAR_PSWD", "createdBy"."MIDDLENAME" AS "CREATEDBY_MIDDLENAME", "createdBy"."CREATED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_CREATED_DATE", "createdBy"."FAILED_LOGINS" AS "CREATEDBY_FAILED_LOGINS", "createdBy"."MOBILE_NUMBER" AS "CREATEDBY_MOBILE_NUMBER", "createdBy"."LAST_LOGIN_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_LAST_LOGIN_DATE", "createdBy"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "createdBy"."ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED" AS "CREATEDBY_ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED", "createdBy"."PROFILE_EXPIRY_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_PROFILE_EXPIRY_DATE", "createdBy"."IS_SELF_SERVICE_USER" AS "CREATEDBY_IS_SELF_SERVICE_USER", "createdBy"."MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE" AS "CREATEDBY_MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE", "createdBy"."ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED" AS "CREATEDBY_ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED", "createdBy"."PASSWORD_NEVER_EXPIRES" AS "CREATEDBY_PASSWORD_NEVER_EXPIRES", "createdBy"."CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED" AS "CREATEDBY_CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED", "createdBy"."LAST_TIME_PASSWORD_UPDATED" AS "CREATEDBY_LAST_TIME_PASSWORD_UPDATED", "createdBy"."FIRST_TIME_LOGIN_REMAINING" AS "CREATEDBY_FIRST_TIME_LOGIN_REMAINING", "lastModifiedBy"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_ID", "lastModifiedBy"."DEL" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEL", "lastModifiedBy"."EMAIL" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_EMAIL", "lastModifiedBy"."STATUS" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STATUS", "lastModifiedBy"."VERSION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_VERSION", "lastModifiedBy"."ENABLED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_ENABLED", "lastModifiedBy"."USERNAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_USERNAME", "lastModifiedBy"."BRANCH_ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_BRANCH_ID", "lastModifiedBy"."PASSWORD" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_PASSWORD", "lastModifiedBy"."LASTNAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_LASTNAME", "lastModifiedBy"."USER_TYPE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_USER_TYPE", "lastModifiedBy"."CLEAR_PSWD" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_CLEAR_PSWD", "lastModifiedBy"."FIRSTNAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_FIRSTNAME", "lastModifiedBy"."MIDDLENAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_MIDDLENAME", "lastModifiedBy"."CREATED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_CREATED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy"."FAILED_LOGINS" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_FAILED_LOGINS", "lastModifiedBy"."MOBILE_NUMBER" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_MOBILE_NUMBER", "lastModifiedBy"."LAST_LOGIN_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_LAST_LOGIN_DATE", "lastModifiedBy"."ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED", "lastModifiedBy"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy"."MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_MOBILE_COUNTRY_CODE", "lastModifiedBy"."PROFILE_EXPIRY_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_PROFILE_EXPIRY_DATE", "lastModifiedBy"."ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED", "lastModifiedBy"."IS_SELF_SERVICE_USER" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_IS_SELF_SERVICE_USER", "lastModifiedBy"."PASSWORD_NEVER_EXPIRES" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_PASSWORD_NEVER_EXPIRES", "lastModifiedBy"."CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED", "lastModifiedBy"."FIRST_TIME_LOGIN_REMAINING" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_FIRST_TIME_LOGIN_REMAINING", "lastModifiedBy"."LAST_TIME_PASSWORD_UPDATED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_LAST_TIME_PASSWORD_UPDATED", "createdBy_staff"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_ID", "createdBy_staff"."ACTIVE" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_ACTIVE", "createdBy_staff"."MOBILE_NO" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_MOBILE_NO", "createdBy_staff"."LASTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_LASTNAME", "createdBy_staff"."FIRSTNAME" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_FIRSTNAME", "createdBy_staff"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_EXTERNAL_ID", "createdBy_staff"."LOAN_OFFICER" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_LOAN_OFFICER", "createdBy_staff"."DISPLAY_NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_DISPLAY_NAME", "createdBy_staff"."JOINING_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_JOINING_DATE", "createdBy_staff"."EMAIL_ADDRESS" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "createdBy_staff"."ORGANISATIONAL_ROLE_TYPE" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_ORGANISATIONAL_ROLE_TYPE", "createdBy_office"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_OFFICE_ID", "createdBy_office"."NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_OFFICE_NAME", "createdBy_office"."HIERARCHY" AS "CREATEDBY_OFFICE_HIERARCHY", "createdBy_office"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "CREATEDBY_OFFICE_EXTERNAL_ID", "createdBy_office"."OPENING_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_OFFICE_OPENING_DATE", "createdBy_tellerId"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_ID", "createdBy_tellerId"."DEL" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_DEL", "createdBy_tellerId"."NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_NAME", "createdBy_tellerId"."VERSION" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_VERSION", "createdBy_tellerId"."TELLER_CODE" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_TELLER_CODE", "createdBy_tellerId"."DESCRIPTION" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_DESCRIPTION", "createdBy_tellerId"."CREATED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_CREATED_DATE", "createdBy_tellerId"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_TELLERID_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "createdBy_departmentId"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_ID", "createdBy_departmentId"."DEL" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEL", "createdBy_departmentId"."VERSION" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_VERSION", "createdBy_departmentId"."CREATED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_CREATED_DATE", "createdBy_departmentId"."DEPARTMENT_NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEPARTMENT_NAME", "createdBy_departmentId"."DEPARTMENT_CODE" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEPARTMENT_CODE", "createdBy_departmentId"."REFERENCE_NUMBER" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_REFERENCE_NUMBER", "createdBy_departmentId"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_ID", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."ACTIVE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_ACTIVE", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."MOBILE_NO" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_MOBILE_NO", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."LASTNAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_LASTNAME", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."FIRSTNAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_FIRSTNAME", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_EXTERNAL_ID", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."DISPLAY_NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_DISPLAY_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."LOAN_OFFICER" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_LOAN_OFFICER", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."JOINING_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_JOINING_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."EMAIL_ADDRESS" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "lastModifiedBy_staff"."ORGANISATIONAL_ROLE_TYPE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_ORGANISATIONAL_ROLE_TYPE", "lastModifiedBy_office"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_OFFICE_ID", "lastModifiedBy_office"."NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_OFFICE_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_office"."HIERARCHY" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_OFFICE_HIERARCHY", "lastModifiedBy_office"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_OFFICE_EXTERNAL_ID", "lastModifiedBy_office"."OPENING_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_OFFICE_OPENING_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_ID", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."DEL" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_DEL", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."VERSION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_VERSION", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."TELLER_CODE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_TELLER_CODE", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."CREATED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_CREATED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."DESCRIPTION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_DESCRIPTION", "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_TELLERID_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_ID", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."DEL" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEL", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."VERSION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_VERSION", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."CREATED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_CREATED_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."DEPARTMENT_CODE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEPARTMENT_CODE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."DEPARTMENT_NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_DEPARTMENT_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."REFERENCE_NUMBER" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_REFERENCE_NUMBER", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", "createdBy_staff_image"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_ID", "createdBy_staff_image"."LOCATION" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_LOCATION", "createdBy_staff_image"."STORAGE_TYPE" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_STORAGE_TYPE", "createdBy_staff_office"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_ID", "createdBy_staff_office"."NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_NAME", "createdBy_staff_office"."HIERARCHY" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_HIERARCHY", "createdBy_staff_office"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_EXTERNAL_ID", "createdBy_staff_office"."OPENING_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_OPENING_DATE", "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_ID", "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_NAME", "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."HIERARCHY" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_HIERARCHY", "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_EXTERNAL_ID", "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."OPENING_DATE" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_OPENING_DATE", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_ID", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."LABEL" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_LABEL", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."POSITION" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_POSITION", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."IS_ACTIVE" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_IS_ACTIVE", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."MANDATORY" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_MANDATORY", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."DESCRIPTION" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_DESCRIPTION", "lastModifiedBy_staff_image"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_ID", "lastModifiedBy_staff_image"."LOCATION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_LOCATION", "lastModifiedBy_staff_image"."STORAGE_TYPE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_IMAGE_STORAGE_TYPE", "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_ID", "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."HIERARCHY" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_HIERARCHY", "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_EXTERNAL_ID", "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."OPENING_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_STAFF_OFFICE_OPENING_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_ID", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."HIERARCHY" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_HIERARCHY", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."EXTERNAL_ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_EXTERNAL_ID", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."OPENING_DATE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_BRANCH_OPENING_DATE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_ID", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."LABEL" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_LABEL", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."POSITION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_POSITION", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."IS_ACTIVE" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_IS_ACTIVE", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."MANDATORY" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_MANDATORY", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."DESCRIPTION" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_DESCRIPTION", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."ID" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_ID", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."NAME" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_NAME", "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."SYSTEM_DEFINED" AS "CREATEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_SYSTEM_DEFINED", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."ID" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_ID", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."NAME" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_NAME", "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."SYSTEM_DEFINED" AS "LASTMODIFIEDBY_DEPARTMENTID_SOURCEPLACECODE_CODE_SYSTEM_DEFINED" FROM "ROLE" LEFT OUTER JOIN "APP_USER" AS "createdBy" ON "createdBy"."ROLE" = "ROLE"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "APP_USER" AS "lastModifiedBy" ON "lastModifiedBy"."ROLE" = "ROLE"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "STAFF" AS "createdBy_staff" ON "createdBy_staff"."APP_USER" = "createdBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "createdBy_office" ON "createdBy_office"."APP_USER" = "createdBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "TELLER" AS "createdBy_tellerId" ON "createdBy_tellerId"."APP_USER" = "createdBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "DEPARTMENT" AS "createdBy_departmentId" ON "createdBy_departmentId"."APP_USER" = "createdBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "STAFF" AS "lastModifiedBy_staff" ON "lastModifiedBy_staff"."APP_USER" = "lastModifiedBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "lastModifiedBy_office" ON "lastModifiedBy_office"."APP_USER" = "lastModifiedBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "TELLER" AS "lastModifiedBy_tellerId" ON "lastModifiedBy_tellerId"."APP_USER" = "lastModifiedBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "DEPARTMENT" AS "lastModifiedBy_departmentId" ON "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."APP_USER" = "lastModifiedBy"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "IMAGE" AS "createdBy_staff_image" ON "createdBy_staff_image"."STAFF" = "createdBy_staff"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "createdBy_staff_office" ON "createdBy_staff_office"."STAFF" = "createdBy_staff"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "createdBy_departmentId_branch" ON "createdBy_departmentId_branch"."DEPARTMENT" = "createdBy_departmentId"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CODE_VALUE" AS "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode" ON "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."DEPARTMENT" = "createdBy_departmentId"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "IMAGE" AS "lastModifiedBy_staff_image" ON "lastModifiedBy_staff_image"."STAFF" = "lastModifiedBy_staff"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "lastModifiedBy_staff_office" ON "lastModifiedBy_staff_office"."STAFF" = "lastModifiedBy_staff"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "OFFICE" AS "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch" ON "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_branch"."DEPARTMENT" = "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CODE_VALUE" AS "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode" ON "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."DEPARTMENT" = "lastModifiedBy_departmentId"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CODE" AS "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code" ON "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."CODE_VALUE" = "createdBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."ID" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CODE" AS "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code" ON "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode_code"."CODE_VALUE" = "lastModifiedBy_departmentId_sourcePlaceCode"."ID" WHERE "ROLE"."APP_USER" = ?]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2INST1.ROLE, DRIVER=4.21.29
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General principles.

There is no concept of lazy loading in Spring Data JDBC.
This is possibly the most important design decision in Spring Data JDBC and it is crucial to understand it:

Spring Data JDBC will load a complete aggregate, including everything that is referenced by normal Java references. Things that should not or must not be part of the same aggregate must not be referenced by a java reference, but only by id. See [Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates) for a more in detail discussion of this.

Projections in the way other Spring Data modules do them, by using an interface as the return value aren't currently supported, but you may use DTOs, i.e. dedicated classes that have a subset of the properties of the entity class, as a return value.

#### What is going on in your case.

`AppUser` seems to have a reference to a `Role` which gets loaded by a separate select statement, which is what you are seeing. This select is not controlled by the query in the annotation. Instead the `AppUser` instance gets initialised by the result from the specified query. Then Spring Data JDBC notes that there are further references and resolves those by the aforementioned SQL statement(s).

I have no idea why you get an exception. Possibly because the query is to long?

#### What you should do

Create a new class `AppUserProjection` containing only the fields in your query and us it as your return value. Since there is no reference to `Role` or other references, no further SQL statments will get executed.

Even better and more important though, I think your domain model is not suitable for use with Spring Data JDBC. `AppUser` and `Role` seem to be two different aggregates and therefore one MUST REFERENCE THE OTHER BY ID. This makes the lazy loading project go away immediately. To navigate from the `AppUser` to the `Role` you use the id to load the `Role` from a separate `RoleRepository`. This even allows you to implement any caching strategy you want.

Apart from references you may populate an entity from a SQL query that does not load all properties. All properties not reflected in the SQL will not be set on the entity and will therefore have their respective default value.
This is not recommended though, because it creates incomplete entities and any code in your entity class needs to handle possibly missing values, which complicates the code. Use dedicated DTOs instead, as described above.

Comment: Hi, Just a follow up comment regarding this, Regarding the Role. It's supposed to be a many-to-one mapping that I am having a hard time implementing. Itried to annotate

public class AppUser {
     @Column("ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;
}

The generated SQL statement doesn't use the ROLE_ID but instead still uses the ID.
Is Many-To-One possible in Spring JDBC ?

Comment: See the referenced article from the answer.